# Can anyone suggest on how to run multiple minus queries at a single and all results must be captured in a single notepad

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
select A.id,A.salary from employee A 
minus
select B.id ,B.salary from Msg b
```

Like the above query I have more than 100 queries of similar type involving different table .If the above query returns 0 records then its a success.Instead of manually executing this query is there any means to execute all queries at a single stretch and even though it is a success or failure all queries must be executed.I have **toad version 9.7**(an additional information)

Comment: Seems like you need to write a stored procedure. Why is there an ID and salary in a table Employee and a table Msg? What are you trying to discover?

Comment: put all the queries in a single editor and hit F5. Note that queries must end with semicolon(;). This is called "running as a script";

Answer (score 1):

May saving you query on a file and then using toad to load and execute scrip file, will be your answer pal.

[image]